# how to Simulate clicking on the checkbox in the component

Tags: react-testing-library, ts-jest

here is my component ,i want to use jest to make test, but i don not know how to Simulate clicking on the checkbox in the component. 'Checkbox' is a component of mui.
Can someone help me? Thank you first.......
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUXpQ.png)

This is from the component being tested:

```
const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rejection checkbox' } };

return (
    <div>
        <section>
            <Title type='large' title='i am large'></Title>
            <AuthButton />
            <div>
                <div>
                    rejected: <Checkbox {...label} onChange={handleChange} checked={checked}></Checkbox>
                </div>
                <button onClick={handlePost}>button text</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a [MUI checkbox](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/) has `role="checkbox"` and this particular use is assigning an accessible name via `aria-label="rejection checkbox"`, you can query for this element [by role](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/) as follows:

```
const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox', { name: /rejection checkbox/i });
```

You may want to assert that this is in the document, so you can add this assertion to your test (this requires [jest-dom](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-jest-dom/)):

```
expect(checkbox).toBeInTheDocument();
```

To simulate a click, the simplest way is to use [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireevent):

```
fireEvent.click(checkbox);
```

If you want to assert that the checkbox has been checked, you can do this (again, using `jest-dom`):

```
expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
```

Putting it all together:

```
test('clicking the checkbox will check it', () => {
  render(<MyTestedComponent />);

  const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox', { name: /rejection checkbox/i });
  expect(checkbox).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(checkbox).not.toBeChecked();

  fireEvent.click(checkbox);
  expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
});
```

This is how you can use react-testing-library to test interactions with a MUI checkbox.  It seems like you may be new to all of this, so I recommend you read the [Getting Started](https://testing-library.com/docs/) section of the testing library docs.